# Django email client

Tags: django, email

I always had the impression that Django email was behaving like an email client and that's why you have to specify an EMAIL_HOST, an EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD and an EMAIL_HOST_USER. The Django app then behaves like an ordinary email client just like Outlook or Apple mail....

I am testing an application which has to send email every once in a while. but when in my app I execute these statements:

```
subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'noreply@dummy.com', 'dummy@gmail.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.send()
```

I am getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
.
.
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'dummy@gmail.com': (504, '5.5.2 <wmsdesktop>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname')}
```

in which wmsdesktop is the name of my development system. From this error I get the impression that the Django app is behaving like a smtp server.

Or am I missing something here. Please shed some light on this...

Comment: Sounds like you have an error in your settings.

Comment: please post your settings codes. I think it's because of your email settings

Answer (score 2):

Every email "client", when sending email, uses SMTP.

SMTP is how email is sent.

So yes, Django is acting as an SMTP client, not an email (POP or IMAP) client, when sending email.

It looks like the STMP server you're using restricts access to only other SMTP servers which have a fully-qualified domain name (example.com) which can be verified through a reverse DNS lookup.

This is a very common practice for SMTP servers, as it helps eliminate anonymous SMTP servers, which are often used for sending SPAM.

Generally speaking, this restriction doesn't apply for authenticated users, though that's dependent on the SMTP server.

Comment: I know every email sender uses smtp. What I don't understand is why the error message. I am using the same smtp server for my ordinary desktop clients.

Comment: I know every email sender uses smtp. What I don't understand is why the error message. I am using the same smtp server for my ordinary desktop clients and that works fine. The error message seems to indicate the Django app is issuing an "helo wmsdesktop" and wmsdesktop is not a fully qualified hostname. I used to use another email server in the past which was on my local network and I never had that issue with that server.

Comment: My SMTP server is Postfix running on FreeBSD.

Comment: You remark about access restrictions only to fully-qualified domain names got me thinking. So I had a look at the Postfix configuration file: main.cf and there was a line reading: smtpd_helo_restrictions = fully-qualified domain name. When I removed that line the whole thing worked. So you remark was brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Wright this code in your **settings.py** file

```
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_PORT = 587
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'email password'
```

And After that use this code in your **view.py** file

```
def sendEmail(request):
    subject, from_email, to = 'Hello', 'noreply@dummy.com', 'dummy@gmail.com'
    text_content = 'Dear Sir,'
    html_content = '<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>'
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Comment: please add some words (i.e. anything not formatted as code) to this answer.